# Usb-harddisk and raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi

Mathematica on raspberry. External media access.
I have a usb harddisk, which is recognized by the system, but apparently not known to Mathematica. The disk is not seen when I try to open files from inside Mathematica. But I can launch Mathematica from the files (right clicking etc).
How do I make these media known inside Mathematica. Observe I am almost without experience in Linux.

Comment: Have you tried `FileNames[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Copy a notebook to the USB disk. Open this by double clicking. Evaluate in the notebook window the function `NotebookFileName[]`. If all is well you should be able to infer the disk name from the result.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. It helped med realize that it isn't a Mathematica problem. My usb-disk is only readable, not writeable. So Probably I must do some linux-handling.